# Como usar o plugin botepage ajax corretamente

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html5

EStou tentando usar esse plugin aqui [botepage](http://botmonster.com/jquery-bootpag/#docs)

o problema é que nao estou conseguindo inserir nenhum conteudo dentro das divs, na pagina 1 por exemplo digamos que eu queira colocar "olá", na pagina 2 digamos que eu queira colocar "oi" como faço para atribuir a pagina 2 a div dois, a pagina 1 a div um, e assim por diante??

segue o meu codigo

```css
<script>
        // init bootpag
        $('#page-selection').bootpag({
            total: 10,
   page: 1
        }).on("page", function(event, /* page number here */ num){
             $("#content").html("page" + num ); // some ajax content loading...
        });
    </script>
```

```html
<div id="content">

<div id="um">

<h1>ola</h1>

</div>

<div id="dois">
<h1>oi</h1>

</div>

</div>
    <div id="page-selection">Pagination goes here</div>
```

e aqui esta o resultado desse codigo no meu site [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

como voces podem ver as duas  divs, aparecem ao msm tempo ao invez da div um, aparecer na pagina 1 e a div dois aparecer na pagina 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pelo que testei, o Bootpag não permite montar a paginação a partir de conteúdo previamente declarado no html como você fez com o div="um" e div="dois", o carregamento é dinâmico, basta ter uma região div com o id "content" e outra "page-selection":

```
<html>
<head>
    <!-- bower:css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css">
    <!-- endbower -->
    <!-- bower:js -->
    <script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/bootpag/lib/jquery.bootpag.js"></script>
    <!-- endbower -->
</head>
<body>
    <div id="content"></div>
    <div id="page-selection">Pagination goes here</div>

    <script>
        // init bootpag
        $('#page-selection').bootpag({
            total: 5,
            page: 3 //Pagina inicial
        }).on("page", function(event, num){
            if(num == 1)
                $("#content").html("<h1>Olá!</h1>"); 
            else if(num == 2)
                $("#content").html("<h1>Oi!</h1>"); 
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Se a página for 1 exibe Olá!, se a página for 2 exibe Oi!. No exemplo coloquei o total de páginas para 5 e a inicial como 3.